# How can I add a LZMA custom compression filter in h5py?

Tags: python, compression, hdf5, h5py, lzma

According to the [h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#dataset-compression) it is possible to add custom compression filters in h5py.

But I don't quite understand how this would work, and I can't seem to find any working examples. (I can only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049670/how-to-specify-a-custom-compression-filter-in-h5py) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/JqaBv98OGMs), but neither give any concrete example on how it works...)

Can someone who knows better please explain with an example perhaps? I am very keen on adding a LZMA filter...

Comment: I'm guessing that you have to add/create the filter at a lower level, working the the `HDF5` library.  The `h5py` enhancement just allows you to specify the id of a filter you created else where.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes the documentation is pretty clear in that sense. But I don't understand how that filter id ties into `h5py` being capable of decompressing using the custom filter. Does it mean I have to edit and build the `h5py` library itself, that is, adding the custom filter in the source code itself? I would instead prefer to configure rather than change the underlying library...

Comment: Looks like you have recompile `hdf5`, https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/compression.html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784595/hdf5-c-with-third-party-filters/39790494#39790494